# Find and delete files using shell

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to delete some files from the working directory, but first list the files to be deleted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
tput bold;
tput setaf 1;
echo "You are about to DELETE ALL auxillary files and Tmp files"
echo "These are the files to be deleted:"
tput sgr0;
for ext in log out aux dvi lof lot bit idx glo bbl bcf ilg toc ind out blg fdb_latexmk fls run.xml pyg pyg.out
do
find . -type f -name "*.$ext" -not -path "./.git/*" -print
done
find Tmp/ -type f
tput setaf 3;
read -s -k "?Press any key to purge!"$'\n'
tput sgr0;
for ext in log out aux dvi lof lot bit idx glo bbl bcf ilg toc ind out blg fdb_latexmk fls run.xml pyg pyg.out
do
find . -type f -name "*.$ext" -not -path "./.git/*" -delete
done
find Tmp/ -type f -delete
tput bold;
tput setaf 1;
echo "DONE"
```

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid repeating a large chunk of code twice.

Comment: Actually, your code is dangerous: If additional files are added while the script is waiting for user input, it might be that files get deleted which are not shown in the prompt. Instead, store the files to be deleted into an array, and then use the array for the actual deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setopt extendedglob

local -a ext=( 
    log out aux dvi lof lot bit idx glo bbl bcf ilg toc ind out blg 
    fdb_latexmk fls run.xml pyg pyg.out
)
local -a files=(
    **/*.${^ext}~./.git/*(N.)
    Tmp/*(N.)
)

print -nP '%B%F{1}'
{
  if ! (( $#files )); then
    print No files to delete!
    return 1
  fi
  print -P You are about to DELETE ALL auxiliary files and Tmp \
           files in '%~'
  print -P These are the files to be deleted:
} always {
  print -nP '%b%f'
}

ls $files

{
  print -nP '%F{3}'
  if ! read -q '?Purge? [yn] '; then
    print -P '\nPurge aborted.'
    return 1
  fi

  rm -f $files

  print -P '\n%B%F{1}DONE'
} always {
  print -nP '%b%f'
}
```

- `extendedglob` enables all kinds of handy [additional pattern matchers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation), such as `~` for negation.
- The [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) `${…}` causes an array to be treated as a [brace expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).
- By default, non-matching patterns in Zsh cause an error. The [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `(N)` causes them to be removed instead.
- `(.)` matches plain files only.
- Passing the `-P` flag to the `print` [builtin command](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) lets you use [prompt escape sequences](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).
- An `always` clause [*always* executes after the preceding block](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Complex-Commands), even after a `return` statement, but never changes the return value.
- `read -q` reads one character and evaluates to `true` only if that character is `y` or `Y`.

Comment: for some reason, if no files match the pattern, it just lists all files for deletion, but doesn't do anything

Comment: It seems that the problem is that if `ls` gets an empty array, it output all the files in pwd. I have solved it using `if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then` `print -nP '%B%F{2}'` `print -P "No files to delete!"` `return 1` `fi`

Comment: Good catch! I updated my answer.

Comment: I now also added links to further reading.